# How to serialize JSON in C# without child

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I created a controller for returning JSON to a mobile application. Given this action:

```
public JsonResult GetFirm(int id)
{
    Firm firm = new Firm();
    firm = dbContext.Firms.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == id);
    string firmString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(firm);
    return Json(firmString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This method(above method) throw self referencing loop error and I write :

```
Firm firm = new Firm();
firm = dbContext.Firms.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == id);
string firmString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(firm, Formatting.None,
    new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    });
return Json(firmString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But this method send object with all child and collections and json include "\" before all attribute.

I want to send json object without child or collections.

Comment: `Json()` takes an object, and not an already serialized string. So just `return Json(firm)`.

Comment: Asp.net core used  Json.NET for serialization and deserialization of json. You can use attributes supported by JSON.net on your model to control how and what is serialized. For ex : you can mark properties in your model that you don't want to serialize with [JsonIgnore](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) attribute.

Comment: @Nish26 thanks I used JsonIgnore and I solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

## Analysis and Issue

Your issue is clearly somewhere in your model you have a circular reference. I am highly confident it is due to you are trying to deserialize a database model (an EF model at a guess) directly. Doing that is not recommended.

A database model will contain references typically to other classes, which in themselves reference back to the first class due to representing a database structure. So you likely have something like:

```
public class ParentItemDataModel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string SomeInfo { get; set; }

    public List<ChildItemDataModel> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildItemDataModel
{
    public ParentItemDataModel Parent { get; set; }

    public string SomeInfo { get; set; }
}
```

So as you can see, a clear reference loop if deserialized.

## Recommendation

Separate your API models returned to clients from your underlying database models by creating a new, simple class that contains only the required information such as:

```
public class ParentItemApiModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string SomeInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can get that information into the model the old-fashioned way:

```
var parentApiModel = new ParentItemApiModel
{
    Id = dataModel.Id,
    SomeInfo = dataModel.SomeInfo
};
```

Or you can do it with an extension method in your data model (so your typically lower core Api model has no reference back up to the database layer):

```
public static class DataModelExtensions
{
    public static ParentItemApiModel ToApiModel(this ParentItemDataModel dataModel)
    {
        return new ParentItemApiModel
        {
            Id = dataModel.Id,
            SomeInfo = dataModel.SomeInfo
        };
    }
}
```

So that now you can do this:

```
var apiModel = dataModel.ToApiModel();
```

Or in your example that would then be:

```
string firmString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(firm.ToApiModel());
```

Or any other way you like.

## Direct fix

If you do not want to fix it by the recommendation, the quickest, simplest way is to flag your data model `Firm` properties that you don't want in the JSON model with [[JsonIgnore]](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm).

Comment: I agree with this answer. It might behoove you to identify the circular reference culprit now and kill it before it perpetuates. Otherwise, you could end up with similar "ignore" solutions all throughout your project.

Comment: Nice explanation, here is an exception, if you have generated model through edmx then u cand apply jsonignore attribute and you shouldnt, the best solution is to create seprate view model

Answer (score -2):

Try returing a string instead of `JsonResult`

```
public string GetFirm(int id)
{

    Firm firm = new Firm();
    firm = dbContext.Firms.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == id);
    string firmString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(firm, Formatting.None,
                new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                });
    return firmString;
}
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what should be done. You should always return `ActionResult` and just pass the settings to the `Json()` method

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto agreed!, By using poco class instance it will obvious that the self referencing occurred,  actually OP should create viewmodel and add nessasury properties to it. so it will removed the self referancing instances,

Comment: Exactly, but your answer doesn't reflect that unfortunately

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto and I cant find any option to ignore self refrencing loop for JSON restult

Comment: This changes nothing. Instead now of returning a JsonResult which goes through a JsonResultExecutor that then writes a string to the response body and sets a ContentType, now returning a string boils down to MVC then wrapping this in a ContentResult and setting the content type now to the wrong type of plain text